# Support of a module and extension of scalars

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $\phi: R \to R'$ be a ring map, and $M$ is an $R$-module. The ring map induces map of specs $\Phi : \operatorname{Spec}(R') \to \operatorname{Spec}(R)$. Then 
$$
\operatorname{Supp} (M \otimes_R R') \subset {\Phi}^{-1}(\operatorname{Supp}(M)),
$$
with equality for finitely generated modules.

I have a "proof" that gives equality for all modules and I can't find my mistake.

Choose a set $\{m_i\}_{i \in I}$ of generators of $M$. Module $M$ is a sum of cyclic modules $M = \sum_i R m_i$, hence

$$
\operatorname{Supp}(M) = \cup_i \operatorname{Supp}(R m_i).
$$

For cyclic modules $R m_i = R/J_i$, where $J_i = \operatorname{Ann}(m_i)$, so $\operatorname{Supp}(R m_i) = V(J_i)$.

For right hand side we get 
$$
{\Phi}^{-1}(\operatorname{Supp}(M))= \Phi^{-1}(\cup_i V(J_i))=\cup_i \Phi^{-1}(V(J_i))=\cup_i V(J_i R').
$$

For the left hand side we use similar argument: $M \otimes_R R' = \sum_i R'(m_i \otimes 1)$, so 
$$
\operatorname{Supp}(M \otimes_R R') = \cup_i \operatorname{Supp}(R'(m_i \otimes 1)).
$$
As before $\operatorname{Supp}(R'(m_i \otimes 1))=V(K_i)$, where $K_i = \operatorname{Ann}(m_i \otimes 1)=\operatorname{Ann}(m_i)R'=J_i R'$, so

$$
\operatorname{Supp}(M \otimes_R R') = \cup_i V(J_i R').
$$
I did not use that $M$ is finitely generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the relevant lemma from the stacks project

https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07T8

The point is that you cannot compute the annihilator of the element $m\otimes1$ as you did unless you know that  $\phi\colon R\to R’$ is flat.

Comment: Thanks! But clearly $J_i R' \subset K_i$, hence $V(K_i) \subset V(J_i R')$ and we get the inclusion as expected. It would be interesting for me to get the inclusion in other direction for finite modules using arguments of this type.